# Liferay 6.2 Form Validation Problems

Tags: javascript, liferay, liferay-aui, liferay-6.2

I've been trying to adapt the validator from [this example](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/using-the-alloyui-form-validator-in-a-portlet) in a LR 6.2 GA6 Portlet. However, I can't get it to work. Curiously the validator-tag isn't working as well.
This is the form I've been using

```
<aui:form name="<portlet:namespace />address" action="<%=doSmthURL %>" id="fm">
<aui:container>
    ...
    <aui:row>
        <aui:col>
            <aui:input name="conditions1" label="text" type="checkbox" id="conditions1">
            </aui:input>
        </aui:col>
    </aui:row>
    <aui:row>
        <aui:col>
            <aui:input name="conditions2" label="conditions2" type="checkbox" id="conditions2"/>
        </aui:col>
    </aui:row>
</aui:container>
<aui:button-row>
    <aui:button type="cancel" value="Back"></aui:button>
    <aui:button type="submit" value="Finish"></aui:button>
</aui:button-row></aui:form>
```

And this is the Aui:Script part

```
<aui:script>
var rules = {
        conditions1:{
            required:true
        },
        conditions2:{
            required:true
        }
}
var fieldStrings = {
        conditions1:{
            required:"Bitte nimm die allgemeinen Geschäftbedingungen an"
        },
        conditions2:{
            required:"Bitte nimm die allgemeinen Geschäftbedingungen an"
        }
}
AUI().use(
        'aui-form-validator',
        function(A) {
           new A.FormValidator(
             {
              boundingBox: "#fm",
              fieldStrings: fieldStrings,
              rules: rules,
              showAllMessages: true
             }
           )
        }
);
```

I am not sure why it isn't working. Since using a validator tag isn't doing anything as well maybe it is a problem with javascript excecution as a whole.

I hope someone can help me.

Kind regards,
JSM

Comment: I suspect that boundingBox attribute is not specified correctly. Would you please try adding `#<portlet:namespace>fm` (because AUI tags added portlet namespace to id/name)

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a `<aui:validator>` tag inside the `<aui:input>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, that documentation is confusing, and needs to be updated.

If you are able, I'd suggest using the `<aui:validator>` inside the `<aui:input>`.

```
<aui:input name="conditions1" label="text" type="checkbox" id="conditions1">
    <aui:validator name="required" errorMessage="Bitte nimm die allgemeinen Geschäftbedingungen an" />
</aui:input>
```

This way Portal is handling all the necessary JS.

If you can't use `<aui:validator`, I'd suggest using `Liferay.Form` to access the Form Validator attached to the form. Because currently, you're attaching an additional one, which may conflict.

```
<aui:script use="liferay-form">
    var form = Liferay.Form.get('<portlet:namespace />fm');

    var oldFieldRules = form.get('fieldRules');

    var newFieldRules = [
        {
            body: function (val, fieldNode, ruleValue) {
                return (val !== '2');
            },
            custom: true,
            errorMessage: 'must-not-equal-2',
            fieldName: 'fooInput',
            validatorName: 'custom_fooInput'
        },
        {
            fieldName: 'fooInput',
            validatorName: 'number'
        }
    ];

    var fieldRules = oldFieldRules.concat(newFieldRules);

    form.set('fieldRules', fieldRules);
</aui:script>
```